# Angular 2, How can I access what components are in the view port?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, viewport

I'm looking into trying to do a lazy load type feature in angular 2. My requirement is that for components that are in a view, I'd like to send out a certain request. This means that when I scroll (up or down) and components are added to the view port, I can trigger this request.

Any direction would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm it took some digging but I found a lazyImageLoader that uses an onscroll event to fire the image loading that might be helpful.
https://github.com/tjoskar/ng2-lazyload-image/blob/master/src/lazyload-image.directive.ts

I'd try and help explain what all of that does, but I am still figuring out all the ins and outs of observables as well.